# Detect client disconnect in serviceworker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is there an event or mechanism that can be used within a serviceworker to detect when a client disconnects, i.e. one of the client instances in *self.clients.matchAll()* changed?

Given the example of an app running in two or more open tabs, how would I proceed in notifying other tabs that one of the other tabs were closed?

My current solution is to maintain a client map within the serviceworker and then run a cleanup function within other commonly used functions of the serviceworker, but given the shared nature of serviceworkers I'm not able to scale this solution without substantial performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found so far:

```js
addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  if (!e.defaultPrevented) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("client_unloaded")
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately beforeunload does not trigger when closing a tab in Android Chrome, when the tab is not in focus. Same goes for unload event.